# Can I Detect the Copy event of React Native TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I want to add additional characters when the values ​​in `React Native` `TextInput` are copied.

If the value of `TextInput` is "Test"
I want to copy the "Test By App" when the user copies it.

I browse `ReactNative` documentation, there is no documentation on TextInput's Copy event.
Do you have any relevant information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Listener for change in clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728263/react-native-listener-for-change-in-clipboard)

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728480/2308005

Comment: Alternatively you can add a copy button to copy the text. Then you can amend any of your signatures to copied text. Please have look on this https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/react-native-basics-copy-to-clipboard-86023cda4175